# How to reformat a big csv file putting a newline every 9 delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I have a big csv file of data delimited by ";" stored in one only huge row.

The first 9 fields separated by a semicolon are the columns name of the entire set.

With Python, how could I reformat this csv file rewriting it and adding a newline every 9 fields for a correct import in Excel or Calc?

Should I import csv or pandas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issues did you have with your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick regex hack that could do the job. This assumes that there are no quoted semicolons in the values:

```py
import re

csv = "a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;"
wrapped = re.sub(r"((?:[^;]*;){9})", r"\1\n", csv)

print(wrapped)
```

This outputs:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;
```

Comment: it worked like a charm. I hadn't the faintest idea that regex could do that and I was struggling with iteration cycles finding the separators!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV fields contain quoted semicolons, this version that uses the [`csv]` module's parser can handle it:

in.csv:

```
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6;col7;col8;col9;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;"a;a";"b;b";"c;c";"d;d";"e;e";"f;f";"g;g";"h;h";"i;i"
```

code:

```py
import csv

with open('in.csv', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    line = next(reader)  # reads the first (and assumed only) line

if len(line) % 9 != 0:
    raise ValueError('line items not a multiple of 9')

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    # slice 9 items at a time and output to file
    for i in range(0, len(line), 9):
        writer.writerow(line[i:i+9])
```

out.csv:

```
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6;col7;col8;col9
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9
"a;a";"b;b";"c;c";"d;d";"e;e";"f;f";"g;g";"h;h";"i;i"
```